# Setting an alarm the correct way

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm using an API to fetch movie releases for my Android app and the release dates are in milliseconds UTC. When I take that release date and set it on the user's phone it gets converted in his time zone and called.

**Example:**

A movie's release date in milliseconds:

> 1509667200000

To UTC time & date:

> Fri Nov 03 2017 00:00:00

To local time & date: (Eastern time, my timezone)

> Thu Nov 02 2017 20:00:00

When I set my alarm

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(releaseDate);
    Date date = calendar.getTime();
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), alarmIntent);
```

Alarm gets called the Nov 02 2017 20:00:00, but it needs to get called on Nov 03 at midnight.

Thank you

Comment: I think you should use `setExact()` instead of `set()` for `alarmManager`. See this doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)

Answer (score 2):

What I did and now it works perfectly:

```
    // Calendar
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(releaseDate);
    Date date = calendar.getTime();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try without `timeZone`

Comment: Yes, same result

Answer (score 1):

Can you try setting the timezone as UTC

```
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked o Alarm app some days.
I have Done my alarm Module for Class Schedule for school.
What I have done was...

```
@Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

            calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
                //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }

            setAlarm(calSet);
        }};

    private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){

        textAlarmPrompt.setText(
                "\n\n***\n"
                + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
                + "***\n");

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
//      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }
```